# WiFi in a kali virtual machine?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, backtrack

I have Kali linux installed on Virtualbox (4.2.12) and the host OS is windows 7. I have bridged the VM with the host OS.The problem is Kali is not able to detect the WiFi interface.

I searched the internet and most of the [forums](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=1791) say that the virtual machine can only identify wireless devices connected via USB and the host machine's WiFi can not be detected by VM.

Assuming that it is true I am wondering how am I able to connect to the internet from the VM when the host machine is only having an active WiFi connection and no wired connection?

Any insights?

P.S. I do not have the privilege to create a tag that is why I am tagging this with backtrack.

Comment: The guest VM takes the bridged connection as ethernet, regardless of the physical method. It's more like the virtual machine does not have the driver for the virtual hardware (the intel networking card).

Comment: So the host WiFi can be used by VM then why the tools like aircrack are not working

Comment: Because as far as the VM is concerned, it doesn't have any wirless card in the machine. If you want to try this, you'll need to install a USB wireless dongle and capture it in the VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably that the interface generated inside the virtual machine is ethernet type, not wifi. With a simple command like

```
# ifconfig
```

you can see all interfaces that are up and running. Since you want to virtualbox to see it as a physical device, you must use USB device in that case, and attach it to the virtual machine from the menu.

Answer (score 2):

The answer I found is a video, but it does tell you how to make this work.

Watch this video: http://www.diy-review.com/4sBQRHowToeBTE1K/Connect-USB-Wireless-Adapter-to-Kali-Linux-in-Virtualbox.html

Physically pulling the USB WIFI adapter out and re-inserting it after you've made the necessary changes in the VM settings seems to be a key component.